# Asynchronous javascript: How to run a function during the execution of another function

Tags: javascript, async-await, asynchronous-javascript

Im trying to wrap my head around asynchronous javascript. So I wrote a function to test some things out. What I'm trying to do is write a scenario where I'm:

1. Putting Popcorn in the microwave
2. During the execution of cooking popcorn I'm pouring drinks (I don't want to have to wait for the popcorn to finish cooking before pouring the drinks)
3. After the popcorn is finished cooking I sprinkle some salt over it (So can't execute before or during the cookPopcorn() function)
4. The movie can begin once both the popcorn has been salted and the drinks are ready

**My Question**

As can be seen in the execution results, listed below, the `cookPopcorn()` function will finish executing before `makingDrinks()` is started. I don't want to have to wait for the popcorn to finish cooking before making my drinks. Is it even possible in JS to run `makingDrinks()` during the execution of `cookPopcorn()` or am I misunderstanding the use case of async/await?

**MovieNight.js**

```
function wait(ms) {
  let start = Date.now(),
    now = start;
  while (now - start < ms) {
    now = Date.now();
  }
}

async function cookPopcorn() {
  console.log("Cooking popcorn: a");
  wait(2000);
  console.log("Cooking popcorn: b");
  wait(2000);
  console.log("Cooking popcorn: c");
  wait(2000);
  return "unsalted";
}

async function makingDrinks() {
  console.log("Making drinks");
  wait(2000);
  return "Drinks finished";
}

async function saltPopcorn(popcorn) {
  if (popcorn.includes("unsalted")) {
    console.log("sprinkling salt over popcorn");
    wait(4000);
    return "salted popcorn";
  } 
}

function startMovie(popcorn, drinks) {
  console.log(`We have ${popcorn} and ${drinks}, so let's start movie...`);
}

async function setupMovieNight() {
  let popcorn = await cookPopcorn(); // starts cooking the popcorn
  let drinks = makingDrinks(); // Pour the drinks while the popcorn is busy cooking
  let saltedPopcorn = await saltPopcorn(popcorn); // Salt the popcorn only after it is finished cooking

  startMovie(saltedPopcorn, drinks); // start the movie only when the popcorn has been salted and the drinks are ready
}

setupMovieNight();
```

In my result cooking a,b,c finish before starting to make drinks. I would like to make drinks in-between cooking a,b or c instead of waiting for the popcorn to finish cooking.

**Result**

`Cooking popcorn: a` 
`Cooking popcorn: b` 
`Cooking popcorn: c` 
`Making drinks` 
`sprinkling salt over popcorn` 
`We have salted popcorn and [object > Promise], so let's start movie...`

Comment: Your main problem is your `wait` function which has a tight loop and doesn't allow other code to run. Change it to `const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))` and make sure to `await` it. Then, you can create a function `makeAndSaltPopcorn` and do `await Promise.all([makeAndSaltPopcorn(), makeDrinks()])` before you start the movie. (Make sure to `await` all asynchronous function calls! The ones inside `Promise.all` are an exception because you want them to run in parallel and you then `await` the resulting combined promise.)

Comment: You are not using `await`, and you are not doing anything asynchronous. Do not use busy waiting for sleeping! It's like you're constantly watching the microwave until it's finished, meaning you don't have time to pour the drinks. You actually need to let go and let the microwave do its thing alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "wait" function is not asynchronous.

It just runs a loop setting `now = Date.now()` repeatedly as fast as it can, blocking anything else from happening, for 2 seconds (or whatever).

You could reimplement it using a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) with [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout):

```js
async function wait (ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    console.log(`waiting ${ms}`);

    // call resolve after the time has elapsed
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('done');
      resolve();
    }, ms);
  })
}

async function go () {
  console.log('start popcorn a');
  await wait(2000);
  console.log('start popcorn b');
  await wait(2000);
  console.log('start popcorn c');
  await wait(2000);
  console.log('done', Date.now());
}

go();
```

You could of course just have `cookPopcorn` do this.

```js
async function cookPopcorn () {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('yay popcorn!'), 2000);
  })
}

function noAwait() {
  // notice that "do other stuff" is logged before "yay popcorn"
  // because we're not awaiting cookPopcorn
  console.log('do stuff, no await.');
  cookPopcorn().then(result => console.log(result));
  console.log('do other stuff, no await.');
}

async function withAwait() {
  // logs in order because we await the popcorn before moving on.
  console.log('do stuff');
  const result = await cookPopcorn();
  console.log(result);
  console.log('do other stuff');
}
```

```html
<button onClick="noAwait()">No Await</button>
<button onClick="withAwait()">With Await</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that clears things up alot! I completely misunderstood the use of await. I'll look more into using Promises for running asynchronous code.